# Response from java soap based web service showing null but has data in xml format

Tags: java, c#, xml, web-services, soap

I am calling a Java soap based web-service which has certificate on it. Seems their response has namespace issues by which the objects are showing null when tested through WCF Test Client tool and we are able to see the response in XML view but not as Formatted view of WCF Test Client.
Could someone help how to parse this web service through C# so that I can consume the XML response out of it. I am trying to consume it in Dot Net - Rest based web service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we your code and the response you are trying to parse?

Comment: You could use [`XDocument.Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx) to load the response stream then parse it with [Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).  Beyond that you're going to need to show us sample code & XML for us to help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we figured it out.
We use JAVA based WCF service in dotnet rest based service as service reference. When we add it we get some fields as nulls but there is data existing. We add those fields manually in servicereference.cs class file and then those values came up.
This is something specific to us. Might not be helpful for other user.